# How was the torpedo that Luke Skywalker shot into the first death star able to make the distance down to the reactor?

Tags: star-wars, luke-skywalker, death-star

How much fuel is in a [proton torpedo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Star_Wars_weapons#Ship-mounted)? How far is the maximum effective range of said torpedo? How far into the interior of the [first Death Star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_Star) (DS-1) is the reactor?

Then there are the technical questions of:

- What is the time delay of the explosive?
- Are there any forces or gases pushing on the progress of the torpedos? Two torpedos—fired at the same hole—are going dozens of miles down the same tube.

Comment: I can't be 100% sure, but I think it was Wookie magic.

Comment: The Force!!!!!!

Comment: "Use The Force Luke"

Comment: I'm not sure the missiles themselves travelled down the exhaust port — "A precise hit will start a chain reaction, which should destroy the station." I've always interrupted this as the missiles exploding once inside the port, and this explosion travelling all the way into the reactor due to bad design of thermal exhaust port allowing a chain reaction to take place.

Comment: @VicSmith yeah that was my impression as well, it wasn't that the torpedo made it to the reactor, its that it blew something up that started a chain reaction that resulted in the reactor blowing up.

Answer (score 30):

While I'm sure someone will come up with a more canonical answer, here's my approach from a pure physics perspective:

Basically, it boils down to **Isaac Newton's Laws of Motion**... and I immediately had to think of the soldier explaining the basics in regard to space combat as seen in Mass Effect 2 (dead link removed)

The most important part is this bit:

> An object that is in motion will not change its velocity unless an external force acts upon it.

What this means is that the torpedo doesn't need enough fuel to burn through the whole (or more specific: half) Death Star.

The torpedo will only consume fuel in the following situations:

- Acceleration
- Deacceleration
- Turning (which - as mentioned in the comments - is just (de)acceleration again)

So in short, it will only use up its energy when it has to steer around or through some obstacle(s) (assuming there's no dense atmosphere inside the shaft).

As depicted in the movie, the shaft is pretty much straight and leads down right into the center/reactor. As such, there's probably not much the torpedo has to do, except that one turn on the surface and probably some additional corrections along the way.

In no way will it have to accelerate all the way down.

Note that sci-fi games, movies and settings in general will forego or simply violate (or forget about) Newton's laws to make things more interesting or fair, e.g. by limiting the effective range of weapon systems.

So is it impossible in a dogfight for a fighter to outrun a missile or torpedo till it burns out? Of course they can, even while considering Newton's laws. It makes it even more logical:

The dumbest thing you might do, is trying to burn aways fleeing from a torpedo or missile in a straight line. Even if Newton's laws are in effect, this will allow the pursuing weapon to follow you for the longest time. Instead, if you try to fly in radical and unpredictable patterns, turning around etc, the missile will have to steer and adjust its path, burning its ressources a lot faster, therefore making the escape a lot easier.

Comment: This is correct, but how it fits in with Lucasian Physics, where space is a sound-carrying medium, and time and distance may be measured in each other's units, I have no idea.

Comment: @Darth Satan: General misunderstanding. You don't measure the time it takes, you measure the shortest distance based on your skill in navigation when using shortcuts through monster dens, ultra-dense asteroid fields, and while abusing interstellar superhighways.

Comment: Don't you be comin' round these here parts with yer fancy book-learnin'.  (yes, I know, I was making a joke)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that in the Star Wars universe, constant thrust = constant velocity. ;-)

Comment: One flaw with this theory is that the Death Star has artificial gravity.  So even though it is in a low density environment the torpedo still has to constantly adjust for gravitational pull.

Comment: We have torpedos today that have a >50km effective range *through water*. If you want to include *missiles*, our current range is much, much further. I don't see why a space-combat civilization wouldn't have developed something that could shoot this kind of distance even through artificial gravity.

Comment: "Acceleration, Deacceleration, Turning" -- All of which are, in the end, acceleration. :P

Comment: Your last paragraph is completely wrong. No matter which way you accelerate, the torpedo will have to match; that *includes* if you accelerate in a straight line. In fact, if you fly in *overly* radical and unpredictable patterns, without waiting for the torpedo to match you in between, you may find yourself in the position of having given the torpedo a "shortcut" to you; going in a straight line, and accelerating as fast as your engines allow, will necessarily maximize the acceleration that the torpedo must match.

Comment: (That said: on Earth, there are various predators that can run very fast in a straight line, but aren't so great at turning (compared to humans). Zigzagging is good advice for getting away from an alligator, for example. The same could be true of a torpedo, if it is better able to accelerate forward than sideways (and if your own ship does not have this limitation). But that's a matter of body mechanics, not of Newtonian physics *per se*. So the best advice is really just "read your ship's *Strategic Operations Manual*". I hope you didn't throw it away?)

Comment: Games violating physics don't make them more interesting - they make them less complex and more accessible by reducing what players (and AIs and UIs) need to learn and deal with. The Death Star's gravity in this case helps the torpedo fall to the center. As for the gripe about evasive maneuvers, lateral evasion can be effective because the target may change the direction the missile needs to travel for a hit, making the missile's own velocity work against a hit, since it needs to overcome its own velocity to change direction, and closing velocity reduces the time it has to do that.

Comment: what about air resistance?  it is an **exhaust** pipe afterall

Comment: @SamIam [By design](http://www.stardestroyer.net/Empire/Tech/Torpedoes/Protorp2.jpg), torpedoes are meant to be very aerodynamic. We also have very little information about any presence of air within the exhaust pipe. Any amount of airflow that would cause a significant change in direction that couldn't be accounted for would likely be in limited bursts, not constant.

Comment: @Dronz It always depends on which aspects are ignored or violated. Imaging some game where you can't fly faster than light since that might not be possible. Suddenly loading screens are your least concern when travelling to another solar system. :)

Comment: The death star had gravity...

Comment: @Machavity Instead of removing a dead link and putting up a notice, could you replace it with an Archive.org link of a previous version of the web page?

Comment: @Thunderforge It was a removed YouTube video. There's no archive of it sadly. But the question was diminished by having the missing video embedded

Answer (score 20):

The torpedo didn't travel to the reactor; it started a chain reaction that did. 
This was explained during the briefing before the [Battle of Yavin](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_Yavin):

> A precise hit will start a chain reaction, which should destroy the station."

See *[Thermal exhaust port](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Thermal_exhaust_port)* (Wookieepedia).

Comment: While canon doesn't give details of the vulnerability, it's not hard to imagine that fabricating an entire exhaust pipe from material which is both physically strong and able to withstand exposure to the exhaust might be difficult.  A pipe with an exhaust-resistant inner layer and a physically-strong outer layer could be much more practical to construct, but a sufficiently large rupture might expose a nearby portion of the outer layer to the exhaust, which would cause it to fail, thus exposing more of the outer layer to the exhaust, etc.  Not every rupture would cause a chain reaction, but...

Comment: ...it's not hard to imagine that a large rupture could do so if it occurred deep enough that exhaust expanding through the rupture would start to experience turbulent flow before it was clear of the station.  Depending upon the pressure and velocity of the exhaust, it may not have been necessary for the torpedo to go very deep in order to create such turbulence; whether the chain reaction could propagate indefinitely inward would depend on the construction of the station near the pipe.

Comment: In particular, there should be sufficient heat and back pressure in the area of the rupture to allow the exhaust there to melt more of the pipe, but not so much heat near the outer parts of the station to expand the outer opening enough to reduce the heat and back pressure to safe levels.  The further the damage works its way down the pipe, the more the exhaust would be able to cool off before reaching the outer layers, so once the damage propagated a certain distance it would be able to propagate indefinitely.

Comment: @jpmc26 if it was fired from a phase cannon, then it is a CANONical answer. Har har har.

Comment: @supercat Your explanation makes a certain degree of sense, especially considering that the original script emphasized that "only a precise hit" would trigger the chain reaction. So they were definitely leveraging some minute flaw in the system, that required a very specific set of circumstances to trigger it.

Comment: @jpmc26: Considering further hypotheticals, even a hit which didn't cause a chain reaction all the way to the reactor might have caused some problems, depending upon what other means of exhausting were available.  If that exhaust port represented 90% of the station's exhaust capability, damaging it could force the station to cut back greatly on energy generation, which might leave it vulnerable to other attacks.  That might have been too expensive to shoot, though, and tried audiences' patience.  Having the whole Death Star go "boom" was cheap and effective.

Comment: @supercat I also like your "fireball" idea from your comment on another answer. The exhaust isn't easily ignited normally (or any blast probably would have done the trick), but finding a way to cause it to ignite could very feasibly destroy the main reactor. Maybe the flaw was that it became possible to trigger such an unlikely situation where the exhaust would ignite.

Comment: @jpmc26: I wasn't thinking of the exhaust itself igniting, but rather having exhaust which is released within the death star contacting, vaporizing, and possibly reacting with the metal of the supporting superstructure.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have to understand that there is some level of gravitational pull from the Death Star, be it artificial or actual. Also, you have to accept the possibility of magnetic shielding within the port itself, which would automatically act as a guide for the torpedo, all the way to the core. In that case, as seen in the movie, they only had to make a direct hit, and the torpedoes would be sucked in and down towards the core, just like you see in the movie. It could have been the shielding, not the force, that caused the 90 degree turn down into the port. It just so happened that to hit that small of a target was nearly impossible for someone without the Force as a guide. That's also why there was no concern about the port being horizontally oriented, because the target area was the effective range of the magnetic shielding, with a strength necessary to pull both torpedoes into the port and towards the core.

Answer (score 0):

To address the chain reaction just inside the port, recall during the briefing the "pong" animation indicated the missile traveled to the center then caused the chain reaction. Minor point of sequence clarification.

Comment: Something in the animation traveled to the center, but it wouldn't have had to be the missile.  High-power electrical cables can suffer a chain-reaction called arc tracking where a spark travels down the cable; heat from the spark burns away the insulation and vaporizes the cable ahead of it, allowing the spark to travel down the cable.  It's not hard to imagine that a similar phenomenon could occur with the pipe feeding the exhaust port; the animated blip moving through the station could have been a "fireball" burning its way down the pipe.

Comment: @supercat a bit of a stretch, but I can see where you're coming from. First rule of presentations - Keep it simple.